# Faking Json using json-schema-faker

Tags: json, json-schema-faker

I am trying to fake a hierarchy of JSON schema which goes atleast 4 levels down, when I tried to use json-schema-faker, I am getting the output with only level 1 and for level 2 I am seeing as [object]. Is there a way to get to all the levels and fake the data.

```
{
    Message: { 
        abcd: [
            [Object], <-- this is level 2 and I am seeing it as [object]
            [Object],
            [Object],
            [Object],
            [Object],
            [Object],
            [Object],
            [Object],
            [Object],
            [Object]
        ]
    }
}
```

Adding the schema

```
{
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "Message": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Message"
    }
},
"required": ["Message"],
"definitions": {
    "Message": {
        "type": "object",
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        "title": "Message",
        "properties": {
            "abcd": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/abcd"
                },
                "uniqueItems": false,
                "name": "abcd",
                "minItems": 5,
                "maxItems": 10
            }
        },
        "ns": "default",
        "searchable": [],
        "validation": [],
        "version": 1,
        "required": ["abcd"]
    },
    "abcd": {
        "type": "object",
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        "title": "abcd",
        "properties": {
            "aa": {
                "type": "number",
                "name": "aa",
                "from": 1
            },
            "bb": {
                "type": "number",
                "name": "bb",
                "from": 1
            }
        },

    }
}
}
```

Comment: We can't really help you without the schema..

Comment: I have added the schema, any help on this is very much appreciated.